# Python Web Scrape Cycle Tabs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Looking for help to loop through all tabs on a website to capture all relevant information.

In the following site, there are a few tabs labelled 5x5, 5x10, 5x15, 10x10, etc. I'm not sure how to structure it so it will go through the tabs and write the loops in my script. Your help is appreciated.

Below is the python script;

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

urls = [
    'https://www.lifestorage.com/storage-units/florida/orlando/32810/610-near-lockhart/?size=5x5'
]

filename = 'life_storage.csv'

f = open(filename, 'a+')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f) 

headers = ['unit_size', 'unit_type', 'description', 'online_price', 'reg_price', 'store_address', 'store_city', 'store_state', 'store_postalcode' ]

##unit_size = 5'x10' withouth the '
##unit_type = climate controlled or not (this could be blank if non-climate)
##descirption = the level it's on and type of access.
##online_price = $##/mo text
##reg_price = the scratched off $## text

csv_writer.writerow(headers)

for my_url in urls:
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')   


    store_locator = page_soup.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "address"})
    containers = page_soup.findAll("ul", {"id": "spaceList"})

    for container in containers:
        for store_location in store_locator:
            store_address1 = store_location.find("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
            store_address = store_address1.text
            store_city1 = store_location.find("span", {"itemprop": "addressLocality"})
            store_city = store_city1.text
            store_state1 = store_location.find("span", {"itemprop": "addressRegion"})
            store_state = store_state1.text
            store_postalcode1 = store_location.find("span", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
            store_postalcode = store_postalcode1.text
            title_container = container.find("div", {"class": "storesRow"})
            unit_size = title_container.text
            unit_container = container.find("div", {"class": "storesRow"})
            unit_type = unit_container.strong.text
            description_container = container.find("ul", {"class": "features"})
            description = description_container.text
            online_price_container = container.find("div", {"class": "priceBox"})
            online_price =  online_price_container.strong.text
            reg_price_container = container.find("div", {"class": "priceBox"})
            reg_price = reg_price_container.i.text

        csv_writer.writerow([unit_size, unit_type, description, online_price, reg_price, store_address, store_city, store_state, store_postalcode])

f.close()
```

Below are snippets from the html body that are related to the loop;

```html
//////////\\\\\\\Description BOX



<div class="storesRow">
    <strong>
<a href="/reservation/choose/?store=610&amp;type=1"> 5' x 5'<sup>*</sup> - Climate Controlled </a>
</strong>
    <ul class="features">
        <li>Indoor access</li>
        <li>Ground Level</li>
    </ul>
</div>



//////////\\\\\\\\\PRICE BOX

<div class="priceBox">
<strong>

                                        $25/mo





                                                <i> $27</i>
</strong>
<em class="pOnly ">Phone &amp; online only</em>
<div class="specialsMessage">
</div>
</div>


//////////\\\\\\\\\ADDRESS BOX


<div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<em>
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
<span itemprop="streetAddress">7244 Overland Rd </span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Orlando</span>,

        <span itemprop="addressRegion">FL</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">32810</span>
</em>
</div>
```

CURRENT OUTPUT
[image]

DESIRED OUTPUT
[image]

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @ Paul - I have edited what is currently the output and what I would like to have. This would loop through all the tabs, so for every new size, it would be put in a new row under the appropriate heading.

Comment: you have wrong indention - `writerow()` should be inside inner `for` - and then it should add all items to your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong indention - `writerow()` should be inside inner `for`.

But it may need more work to extrude correct text from items. See in code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

urls = [
    'https://www.lifestorage.com/storage-units/florida/orlando/32810/610-near-lockhart/?size=5x5'
]

filename = 'life_storage.csv'

f = open(filename, 'a+')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f) 

headers = ['unit_size', 'unit_type', 'description', 'online_price', 'reg_price', 'store_address', 'store_city', 'store_state', 'store_postalcode' ]

##unit_size = 5'x10' withouth the '
##unit_type = climate controlled or not (this could be blank if non-climate)
##descirption = the level it's on and type of access.
##online_price = $##/mo text
##reg_price = the scratched off $## text

csv_writer.writerow(headers)

for my_url in urls:
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')   

    store_location = page_soup.find("div", {"itemprop": "address"})

    # need `li`
    containers = page_soup.find("ul", {"id": "spaceList"}).findAll('li')
    print('len(containers):', len(containers))

    item = store_location.find("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
    store_address = item.text.strip()

    item = store_location.find("span", {"itemprop": "addressLocality"})
    store_city = item.text.strip()

    item = store_location.find("span", {"itemprop": "addressRegion"})
    store_state = item.text.strip()

    item = store_location.find("span", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
    store_postalcode = item.text.strip()

    for container in containers:
        item = container.find("div", {"class": "storesRow"})

        if item and item.strong:
            text = item.strong.text.strip()
            parts = text.split('-')
            if len(parts) > 0:
                unit_size = parts[0].strip().replace('*', "")
            else:
                unit_size = ''

            if len(parts) > 1:
                unit_type = parts[1].strip()
            else:
                unit_type = ''
        else:
            continue

        item = container.find("ul", {"class": "features"})

        if item:
            description = item.text.strip().replace("\n", ',')
        else:
            description = ''

        item = container.find("div", {"class": "priceBox"})

        if item and item.i:
            reg_price = item.i.text.strip()
        else:
            reg_price = ''

        if item and item.strong:
            if item.i:
                item.i.extract() # remove <i>`
            online_price = item.strong.text.strip()
        else:
            online_price = ''

        csv_writer.writerow([unit_size, unit_type, description, online_price, reg_price, store_address, store_city, store_state, store_postalcode])

f.close()
```

Result:

```
unit_size,unit_type,description,online_price,reg_price,store_address,store_city,store_state,store_postalcode
5' x 5',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",$25/mo,$27,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
5' x 5',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",Check for Availability,,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
5' x 10',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",$46/mo,$50,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 5',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",$57/mo,$62,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
5' x 10',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",$67/mo,$73,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
5' x 10',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",Check for Availability,,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
5' x 15',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",$69/mo,$75,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 10',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",$105/mo,$115,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 10',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",$105/mo,$115,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 10',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",$124/mo,$136,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 15',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",$144/mo,$158,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 16',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",$145/mo,$159,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 15',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",$149/mo,$163,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 18',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",$149/mo,$163,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 15',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",Check for Availability,,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 20',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",$147/mo,$161,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 25',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",$175/mo,$192,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 20',Climate Controlled,"Indoor access,Ground Level",Check for Availability,,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
10' x 28',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",Check for Availability,,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
41' x 41',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",$1400/mo,$1540,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
22' x 25',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",Check for Availability,,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
18' x 38',,"Outdoor/Drive-up access,Ground Level",Check for Availability,,7244 Overland Rd,Orlando,FL,32810
```

Comment: @ Furas - Dziękuję